# Moshe losing kehuna

Tags: kohen-priest, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-shemos, aharon

After Moshe asks Hashem to 'send by the hand of whomever You will send' ([Shemos 4:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9865#v=13&showrashi=true)), Rashi notes on (14) that Moshe loses the kehuna to Aharon. Why does Moshe deserve to lose the kehuna based on his reluctance to take on the leadership at first?

**Rashi**

> **with whom You would send:** With whom You are accustomed to sending, and this is Aaron. Another explanation: With someone else, with whom
>   You wish to send, for I am not destined to bring them into the land
>   [of Israel] and to be their redeemer in the future. You have many
>   messengers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rabbi Zweig answered in this week's Insights:

"Aharon recognized that while it’s true
that redeeming Bnei Yisroel and
becoming their leader was a position
of greatness, it’s not an appointment.
In other words, when Hashem asks
you to take this role, it’s one primarily
of service to Bnei Yisroel and
Hashem's plan for the world. This job
isn't about the stature that comes
with the responsibility, it’s about
being a servant to that responsibility.

Moshe was bothered by the stature
associated with the job. He spends a
week explaining why he isn't the right
person for this job. When at the of the
week he still feels that Aharon would
be jealous of his new position,
Hashem gets angry and explains to
him that Aharon understands that this
is about responsibility to serve – not
the associated stature. It is for this
reason that Moshe loses the right to
be a Kohen and this role is given to
Aharon. Kohanim are “Meshorsei
Hamelech” – ministers of the king.
There is no sense of stature in this
leadership role; only responsibility to
serve Hashem. Aharon understood
that when called to the responsibility
of serving Hashem you have to accept
and that stature plays no role in the
decision."

[You can read the full answer here.](http://www.parsha.net/pdf/Shmos/Shmos77.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Different jobs have different requirements. A Kohen's job is to follow Hashem's commandments to the letter whether or not he thinks it would be better a different way. If he doesn't he will very often invalidate his service. For example, if a Kohen decides while he is bringing the Korban that he can make a bigger Kiddush Hashem by eating the Korban a few days later (while he has many guests over who will see or something like that) he has just done a Lav and invalidated the Korban by making it Piggul.

If he is bringing a Korban for a great Rav who is a Yisrael he does not have the ability to tell the Yisrael to do any services beyond the Shechitah.

Someone who has an attitude of deciding that other people should be doing the Avoda when they themselves were the person Hashem asked is someone who does not meet the job requirements to be a Kohen. This does not preclude him from being given other perhaps more important jobs that don't have that job requirement.

Comment: Interesting idea! Is it your own?

Comment: See also _Rashi_ at the beginning of _B'haalos'cha_: "מלמד שבחו של אהרן שלא שינה".

Comment: @msh210 that's the vort of the Brisker Rav.